# Removing first character of every column name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops

The following code works:

```
print(ee.columns[0][1:])
```

But when I generalise this to all columns, the code does not work:

```
ee.columns = ee.columns.astype(str)
for i in range(0,len(ee.columns)-1):
    ee.columns[i] = ee.columns[i][1:]
```

I get the error: 'Index does not support mutable operations'.

Note that ee.columns looks like: [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily do this by using the string accessor `str` and selecting from the 1st element onwards:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str[1:]
```

Comment: Short and effective.

Answer (score 1):

yatu answer is really good because it answers your answer perfectly, as in 'how can i take out the first character', but if you want something more robust...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A0' : [1, 2],
        'A1' : [2, 2],
        'A2' : [3, 2],
        '3A' : [4, 2],
        'A4' : [5, 2],
        'A5' : [6, 2]

    })
print(df.head())
#    A0  A1  A2  3A  A4  A5
# 0   1   2   3   4   5   6
# 1   2   2   2   2   2   2

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'^A', '')
print(df.head())
#    0  1  2  3A  4  5
# 0  1  2  3  4  5  6
# 1  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

As you can see, I replaced your column names using a regex pattern with a technique as simple as the first one. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
ee.rename({c: c[1:] for c in ee.columns if c.startswith('M')}, axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs due to you updating the contents of the index list on the fly. The reason being that pandas Index are [immutable](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Index.html).

```
ee.columns = [i[1:] for i in ee.columns]
```